# Need to get the first cells of a selected row in datagridview before delete it

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.pronv.SelectedRows)
        pronv.Rows.RemoveAt(item.Index);        
}
```

above is my code to delete a selected Row, but before that, i need to get data from the first cell of that row. But when i try:

`pronv.SeletedRows.Cells[0]`

the error says :

> No extensions method "Cells"

I'm stuck here, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SelectedRows` is a collection of rows. You should get cell of one particular row when enumerating selected rows:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.pronv.SelectedRows)
{
    object data = item.Cells[0].Value;
    pronv.Rows.RemoveAt(item.Index); 
}
```